# How to do many to many matching with condition in Python?

Tags: python, many-to-many

please help me how to tackle the many to many matching with condition ?

```
import pandas as pd 
company1 = {'Product': ['Pro_1','Pro_3','Pro_3','Pro_5'],
        'product_date': ['2013-05-09','2012-12-02','2013-10-25','2016-08-25']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(company1, columns = ['Product', 'product_date'])  
print (df)

company2 = {'Product': ['Pro_1','Pro_2','Pro_2','Pro_3','Pro_3','Pro_3','Pro_3','Pro_5','Pro_5'],
        'Start': ['2013-01-01','2012-01-02','2013-01-02','2014-01-01','2011-01-02','2012-01-02','2013-01-02','2014-01-25', '2017-01-26'],
        'end': ['2014-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-12-31','2014-12-01','2012-01-01','2013-01-01','2013-12-31','2017-01-25', '2018-01-20'],
        'inventory': [20,30,50,30,40,10,20,30,20]} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(company2, columns = ['Product', 'Start','end','inventory']) 
print (df2)

result = {'Product': ['Pro_1','Pro_3','Pro_3','Pro_5'],
        'inventory': [20,10,20,30]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns = ['Product', 'inventory'])
print(df3)
```

I wanted to take the match df1 and df2 by the 'Product' and condition on the 'product_date' between the 'Start' and 'end' dates, then return the 'inventory' from df2.